# How to i add a number to a string?

Tags: c++

I want to do something like this (showing what FPS im running at in my SDL game):

```
SDL_WM_SetCaption("FPS: " + GetTicks(&fps)/1000.f, NULL);
```

But Visual Studio intellisens complains that expression must have integral or enum type.

What have i done wrong?

Comment: If it's C++, you should be looking at `std::string`.

Comment: removed SDL tag: this question is about string formatting in C++, not about SDL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this really is C++, consider streams;

```
std::ostringstream str;    
str << "FPS: " << GetTicks(&fps)/1000.;    
SDL_WM_SetCaption(str.str().c_str(), NULL);
```

Answer (score 5):

C does not support conversion of simple types (like `int` or `float`) to more complex types (like strings).

You should check the `sprintf` function:

```
char buffer[64];
sprintf("FPS: %f", GetTicks(&fps)/1000.f);
SDL_WM_SetCaption(buffer, NULL);
```

Comment: It is a C++ question, not a C one (edit: I realise the question has been edited)

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can do this using `sprintf`.

Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf(v=vs.71).aspx

Don't use `+` for adding char pointers (that's what they are in C, not strings).

EDIT:

If this is C++, as per the edit, use `std::string`, which has the `+` operator overloaded. You'll still need to convert the number to a string though.

Also, it's called **concatenation**.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use strings, or if you are already settling for the new current C++ standard, there is also `std::to_string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::string str = "Foobar " + std::to_string(42);
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```